# MariaDB replication hangs without any error

Tags: mysql, networking, mariadb, database-replication

We have some replication connections between mariadb-servers, most of them are master-slave-connections (same versions on master and slave). From time to time, but regularly, a connection seems to stop working. But there is no error, the IO- and the SQL-Running-threads are running. in these cases we only notice missing values on the slave, and then I stop and start the slave again, and after this we have a Seconds_behind_master > 0, before not.
I've learned now something about the variable [MASTER_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/change-master-to/#master_heartbeat_period), but it's enabled with the default value (30 sec), and it seems not working too.
What can be the reason of this strange behavior? What can we do?

EDIT: After some research (a scheduled event on master and slave: on master it writes a current timestamp in an table, on slave it saves the difference of this timestamp to current time) I found out, that we have these slave stoppings regularly after a couple of hours. And the slave is starting again after exact 7200 secs (2h). It happened now two times in 11 hours. What can it be?

EDIT2: Further investigation shows that the phenomenon probably not is caused by mariadb. I have monitored a few connections (described in my first edit), and this way I found out, that only the replications with masters from VMs of a specific host (MS Hyper-V) do delay, and they delay absolute in sync. I think, the reason for the delays (until 7200sec, then the delays disappear) must be on this host.
But - we have some master-master-replications with the instances on these VMs too, but the problem does not appear in this connections. And we dont have the problem on other replication connections on our Slave-VM from VMs from another hosts. Strange.

EDIT3: Well, it's probably not an DNS problem. A few days ago I switched all master addresses to ip, and I setted skip_no_resolve. But nothing changed. There are two main times in a day where it happens everytime (about 05:58 and 10:15). Interestingly the first time (05:58) is relativly constant, but the second time (10:15) goes about 30 seconds in the future every day (from 10:11 on 19.10. to now 10:19). And, interesting too, in the night from 27. to 28.10. we had a change in time (summer to winter time, +1h), the second time (10:15) changed too (before 28.10. it was every 11:15, now it's about every 10:15). The first time 05:58 didn't changed.
And (I know, I should have done it a long time ago) I have in the mysql error log everytime 2 entrys:

`2018-11-06 10:19:50 6172 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query (server_errno=2013)`

`2018-11-06 10:19:50 6172 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log event, reconnecting to retry, log 'mysql-bin.002007' at position 113739713`

Well, something lets the replication stops twice a day (about 03:58 and 08:15) without any error, nearly the same times, but the second time about 20 - 30 seconds later every day, and after 2 hours mariadb becomes aware of this, prints these 2 messages to the log and reconnects the slave. I'm helpless.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`, `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%slave%';`, `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%slave%';`

Comment: Do you think these information are helpful furthermore? Then I will insert it in my post. I'm not shure after the latest insights.

Comment: My request is somewhat a 'shot in the dark'; but, who knows, there might be an 'aha! moment' -- something we did not think of may present itself.

Comment: Sure. No MASTER STATUS, because we don't need a binary log; it's only a slave.
[SLAVE STATUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5CiB.png), [SLAVE VARIABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXMKy.png), [GLOBAL STATUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lyJv.png)

Comment: Eh?  A binlog (on the Master) is necessary for Replication.  And the Master will have a `MASTER STATUS`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course. Thought, you mean the binlog info of the slave. But, here they are: [MASTER STATUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Dq9.png) and [SLAVE STATUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNDa9.png). At this moment the slave is about 1.000 sec after the master. With no errors.

Comment: Re 7200:  Do you get anything from `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VALUE BETWEEN 7000 AND 7444;` ?

Comment: No, nothing. But like I say, I think, it has nothing to do with MariaDB. Some independent replication connections has the same delay in same time. And it seems, it occurs in same times a day. Something happens on a involved server results in these delays on all replication slaves.

Comment: Hmmm...  Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'net%';`.

Comment: Ok: net_buffer_length:16384, net_read_timeout: 30, net_retry_count: 10, net_write_timeout: 60

Comment: Alas, I was hoping to come up with something to make 7200.  Are there any cron jobs or MySQL `EVENTs`?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. No cron jobs (it's all on windows), no scheduled (windows) tasks, and until the tests to determine the phenomenon the event scheduler in mariadb was off on all instances.
But I think, I know the reason of this delays now. It's probably DNS problems on one host. Some replication connections with almost same configuration are not affected, and the only difference I see is: the master in replication configuration is given as IP, not as url. Now I have changed this, and tomorrow I will know, if the delays are disappeared. I will give an update then.

Comment: See also `skip-name-resolve`.

Answer (score 0):

Now we solved the problem. We updated mariadb from version 10.1.X to 10.3.7, and the problem disappeared. We have a few mariadb instances with different versions, and the problem occured only on versions 10.1.X, but not on all. And I still think, the reason for the delays came from outside mariadb, and still we don't have any idea, what the reason could be. But, now it's not our problem anymore. The update solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Adding:

```
   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Solved the problem for me on MySQL 8.0.13 installation.
Read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

And see also this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232365/mysql-8-0-updates-are-sometimes-stalling/271061#271061